# Extract c++ derived class object in boost python

Tags: c++, boost-python

I am trying to get c++ derived class object in python but i did not find any help in boost python. The question is that is this possible to that i can make object in c++ and that object will be accessable in python.

Comment: When you say "c++ derived class object" do you mean a C++ class?

Comment: yes derived class is also in c++

Comment: Does the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20224626/1053968) to your other question demonstrate what you want?  It makes an object in C++ that is accessible in Python, and the C++ object is of a type that derives from a class that has been exposed to Boost.Python.

Comment: No, actually is there anyway that i create object in main  and  access this object from python.

Comment: It should be possible.  Can you please provide code examples as to what you want to accomplish?  It may identify constraints that affect the solution.

Answer (score 1):

I think I maybe had the same issue. 
I have a `Base` class and a `Derived` class both concrete and exposed to python.

```
class Base
{
public:
    virtual ~Base() {}
};

class Derived : public Base
{};

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(inheritance)
{
    boost::python::class_<Base>("Base") ;
    boost::python::class_<Derived, boost::python::bases<Base> >("Derived") ;
}
```

Then I have an instance of `Derived` class seen as a `Base` reference and trying to pass it to python with correct converted type.

```
int main()
{
    Py_Initialize();
    initinheritance() ;

    boost::python::api::object main_module = boost::python::import("__main__");
    boost::python::api::object main_namespace = main_module.attr("__dict__");

    Derived derived ;
    const Base& base = derived ;

    // argh: 'base' is seen as python 'Base' class instance
    main_namespace["base"] = base ; 
    boost::python::exec("print base",main_namespace) ;

    // python 'var' is seen as python 'Derived' class instance 
    // when using C++ pointer and boost::python::ptr 
    main_namespace["var"] = boost::python::ptr(&base) ; 
    boost::python::exec("print var",main_namespace) ;


    Py_Finalize();

    return 0;
}
```

Execution prints :

```
<inheritance.Base object at 0x0042CC70>
<inheritance.Derived object at 0x0042CC38>
```

I had to use `boost::python::ptr` and a C++ pointer.
It also works when having a `Base*` pointing to a real `Base` object.

Maybe it is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Given

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    void some_method();
};
```

In your `BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE` add your class and its methods
e.g.

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>
using namespace boost::python;

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(test)
{
    class_<MyNamespace::MyClass>("MyClass") 
        .def("some_method", &MyNamespace::MyClass::some_method)
    ;  
}
```

Then call these in python

```
import test
myClass = test.MyClass()
myClass.some_method()
```

There are details [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/python/doc/tutorial/doc/html/python/exposing.html)

If you want base and derived class you can do this:

```
class_<Base>("Base")
/*...*/
;

class_<Derived, bases<Base> >("Derived")
/*...*/
;
```

Comment: is there any way that i can create object of derived class(derived class is in c++) and then i can access this object in python?

Comment: Using the 2nd set of classes, just say `myClass = test.Derived()`

Comment: actullay i would like to create this object(myClass = test.Derived()) in c++ class, not in python.

Comment: So, you want to create an instance in C++ and expose that one instance to python?